# How can I prove the assertion for a Graph G?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let G be a graph and A be the adjacency matrix of G. Let $ \delta(G)$ be the minimum degree of G and $\lambda_{min} $ be the least eigen value of A. Show that $\lambda_{min} \leq \delta(G)$.

Comment: The least eigenvalue cannot be positive.

Comment: But why the least eigen value can not be positive?

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ is zero.